# MBP headphone jack red light

Tags: 16.04

After installing Ubuntu to my MBP, occasionally my headphone jack emits a red light, it still functions correctly but is somewhat annoying to have a red led blasting at my roommate late at night.

Comment: That would be the laser for the combo SPDIF output. Congrats on trying Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply open `alsamixer` on the `terminal` and mute the `SPDIF` channels.

The red light should disappear in a couple of minutes.